# Firebase Notification is not working on Android O

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, android-8.0-oreo

I'm using Android O Emulator and want to get notification from Firebase console.It is working fine on every device except Android O. I'm getting this Error in Log.

```
W/Notification: Use of stream types is deprecated for operations other than volume control
W/Notification: See the documentation of setSound() for what to use instead with android.media.AudioAttributes to qualify your playback use case
```

I know that I have to specify Channel id for that . 
So What I have done so far

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
     <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:largeHeap="true"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
                android:resource="@drawable/attach" />


            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
                android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
                android:value="my_notification_channel" />

            <service android:name=".Helper.FirebaseIDService">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </service>

            <service android:name=".Helper.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </service>

       <my all activities...>
```

I've also specify channel id in **FirebaseMessagingService** like this

```
 public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "FCM Service";
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private static final String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "my_notification_channel";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "My Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

            // Configure the notification channel.
            notificationChannel.setDescription("Channel description");
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }


        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Title")
                .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);

        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
 }
}
```

So after doing all this . I still got that error message in log and can't receive notification from console.Any Help would be appreciable.

Comment: any reason behind downvoting ?

Comment: Are you seeing the `From:` log message indicating the message is received?

Comment: when  app is in foreground then I can see that . but after app goes to background its shows that error.@BobSnyder

Comment: Firebase [support for notification channels](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) was added in version 10.2.6.  Are you building with that version or greater?

Comment: @Tej Can you please help me with the same issue .....how did you fix the issue in your project ? where did you create the notification channel in your project ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an FCM message contains no data payload, only a notification payload, and your app is in the background, Firebase generates the notification directly and does not call `onMessageReceived()`.  This is explained in [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages).

For Android O, a notification channel must be created.  You are correctly defining the default notification channel in your manifest, but the channel is created in the `onMessageReceived()` code, which does not execute when the app is in the background.

Move the code that creates the channel somewhere that you can be certain it will execute before a notification is received.

Also, as indicated in the [Firebase Release Notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android), support for notification channels was added in version 10.2.6.  You must build with at least that version.